# JQuery Click On Appended Elements Not Working For Dropdown

Tags: jquery, delegates, click, append, bind

I'm having trouble getting my dropdown menu to still work after I empty it's contents and append new ones.

Here is the page I am having trouble with (try selecting a wallpaper resolution initially, then selecting a different wallpaper from the 5 at the top and try again):
http://www.nba.com/warriors/wallpapertest_020.html

In $(document).ready I have:

```
        $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
            var text = $(this).html();
            $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
            $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
        });
```

This works fine the first time around, but when I change up the contents of the dropdown, it stops working. Is there a way to recall the .ready() function to recognize the new additions? Or a better way to do this?

I also tried delegate() like so, but that stops it from functioning entirely:

```
       $(".dropdown dd ul li").delegate('a', 'click', function() {
            var text = $(this).html();
            $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
            $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
        });
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried to use .on() ?

Comment: @Sven The problem still persists: [(nba.com/warriors/wallpapertest_021.html)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `on()`

```
$(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
            var text = $(this).html();
            $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
            $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
        });
```

Comment: The problem still persists: [(http://www.nba.com/warriors/wallpapertest_021.html)]

Comment: try posting some relevant html. I'm on a slower laptop and can barely manage to debug the page.

Comment: hey I got it to work using live(): `$(".dropdown dd ul li a").live('click', function() {` . I was under the impression that using live() is not good practice though...

Comment: You must be using an older version of jquery. `.live` was deprecated and replaced with `.on` http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: importing 'jquery-1.7.2.min.js' isn't that the newest release?

Comment: jquery noob here..  same problem.. same solution.  But it makes no sense to me - because i am using `jquery-1.7.2.min.js`, and `.live` is supposed to be depreciated... but `.on` is failing (in my case) while `.live` is working.